# How to get the number of column values in Excel without using VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Without using VBA, I would like to get the number of 'Completed' and 'Incomplete' for each of the group -

[image]

I wish to display the 'Completed' and Incomplete' similar to the screenshot below. Is that possible by using a formula and without using VBA?

[image]

Comment: From your example it is unclear what the figures denote: the total number of "complete" jobs of that category over the whole range? And what is "Incomplete|Production"="0|0" ??

Comment: It is not clear to me how you obtain your results from your example.  You show six lines `Completed|System` but your count in the results table is only 3.  Please clarify your question so as to indicate how you are doing your computation.  And also show what you have tried, and what errors your method has produced.

Answer (score 1):

Would the formula =sumif() around the range work for you?

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

Assuming the column with incomplete/complete is Column A then:
You can do =sumif([Column B], [cell with name of group], [Column C])

Answer (score 1):

Use the [COUNTIFS()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1):

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)
```